# Finding the Matrix Power of a matrix and limit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the matrix power, $A^k$, of

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & 1-a \\ b & 1-b\end{pmatrix}$$
$$D=P^{-1}AP$$
$$A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$$

I think that 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{a-1}{b} \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \ \ \  \text{and}\ \ \ \ P^{-1}=\frac{b}{1+b-a}\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{1-a}{b}\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

I found $A^k$ to be $\begin{pmatrix}1& (a-1)/b(1-b)^k\\1&(a-b)^k\end{pmatrix}$.

What would the limit of $A^k$ be when $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: You know that $A$ and $D$ have the same eigenvalues (because they have the same characteristic polynomial).  This lets you find $D$, at which point solving for $P$ is not so hard (it's just "algebra").

Comment: Please check to see that I rendered your matrix correctly.

Comment: Since your space is finite dimensional, convergence $\Leftrightarrow$ coordinate-wise convergence. So it depends on what $a$ and $b$ are in your case. In some cases, it won't converge ($a-b>1$ for example). Also, notice that $X\mapsto XP$ is continuous. Therefore, you have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A^n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} PD^nP^{-1}= P(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}D^n)P^{-1}$ so you could've taken the limit before multiplying the matrices together.

Answer (score 4):

A = $\begin{bmatrix}1-a \\ b & 1-b\end{bmatrix}$

Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and writing the matrix in Jordan Normal Form yields:

$\displaystyle A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 1-a \\ b & 1-b\end{bmatrix} = P.D.P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{a-1}{b} \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & a-b\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1} & -\frac{a-1}{{(-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1})b} \\ -\frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1} & \frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1}\end{bmatrix}$

Now, raising $A^k = (P.D.P^{-1})^k$ is just a matter of raising the diagonal matrix to a power (which is straightforward), yielding:

$\displaystyle A^k = \begin{bmatrix}a & 1-a \\ b & 1-b\end{bmatrix}^k = (P.D.P^{-1})^k$

$\displaystyle = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{a-1}{b} \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & a-b\end{bmatrix}^k \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1} & -\frac{a-1}{{(-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1})b} \\ -\frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1} & \frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1}\end{bmatrix}$

$\displaystyle  = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{a-1}{b} \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & (a-b)^k\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1} & -\frac{a-1}{{(-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1})b} \\ -\frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1} & \frac{1}{-\frac{a}{b} +\frac{1}{b} +1}\end{bmatrix}$

You can handle the rest by multiplying out the three matrices.

Comment: My goodness: a lot of formatting that must have been! +1 for the great answer!

Comment: I get tripped up with lots of fractions, for some reason. I think it's all the $\{,\}$'s that gets me (almost) everytime!

Comment: @amWhy: Trust me, I messed those up too and it was tough getting them straight!